# Display part of html conditionally, does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, asp.net-mvc

My page has 2 main parts:
1: part one is shown with form load.
2: part two is shown using ajax call based on clicking the button in part 1.

In part two, I have 3 subparts:
2-1: first is info.
2-2: second is a checkbox.
2-3: third is as a form for create a request (contains input text boxes).

2-2 will be shown if an int parameter is less or equal to zero.
2-3 will be shown if the parameter is bigger than zero, or the checkbox above is checked.

But it doesn't work.
UPDATE: The conditions has no affects on the *useNextPeriodConfirm* and the  *request* div. Their display is none as initial time.

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {   
        return View();
    }
```

The view:

```
....
<script>
        var id;
        $(function() {
            $("#getCipContent").click(function() {
                loadCipContent();
            });
        });

        function loadCipContent() {

            $.ajax({
                url: ........../GetFilledContent/' + id,
                type: 'get',
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#cipContent").html(data);
                }

            });
        };
    </script>
```

The action method for ajax call:

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetFilledContent(string id)
    {
      .......
        ViewBag.Requests = Requests;
        if (Requests[0].RemaindQuota <= 0)
        {
            ViewBag.FromNextPeroidQuota = true;
        }


        return PartialView("_GetFilledContent", myModel);
    }
```

And the partial view:

```
@model MyModel
<div>
PAERT 2-1
</div>

<div id="useNextPeriodConfirm" class="row" style="display: none">
    @Html.CheckBox("useNextPeriod", false, new { style = "display: inline-block", onchange ="useNextPeriod(this);" })
    <label style="display: inline">I am agree</label>
</div>


<div id="request" style="display: none;">

</div>


<script>
       window.setTimeout(function() {

        if (@ViewBag.FromNextPeroidQuota === true) {
            $("#request").hide();
            $("#useNextPeriodConfirm").show();
        } else {
            $("#useNextPeriodConfirm").hide();
            $("#request").show();
        };

       }, 100);

    function useNextPeriod(item) {
        if (item.checked) {
            $("#request").show();
        } else {
            $("#request").hide();
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: What is not working? What are you expecting to happen, and what is actually happening. (and scripts should never be in partials - only the main view or its layout)

Comment: I updated the question: (What is not working)

Comment: what's wrong with using scripts in partial? Is not efficient that I have used  window.setTimeout?

Comment: What is the point of the `.setTimeout()`?  And `if (@ViewBag.FromNextPeroidQuota === true) {` would throw a syntax error  , and that code would evaluate to `True == true` and result in another error (`True is not defined`). You cannot mix server side and client side code like that.